# How to select an element based on tag name?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I need to select an element base on its tag name. So i used (python and lxml) and did this:

```
doc.getroot().xpath("//SimpleData")
```

But it always return [].

When i do this however:

```
doc.getroot().xpath("//*")
```

I get a long list of results, one of which is this:

```
Element {http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}SimpleData at 0x7ff548098c88
```

So I would like to know what am I doing wrong? Why isnt xpath returning the SimpleData elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to handle namespaces, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255277/lxml-etree-xmlparser-namespace-problem.

Comment: Damn, meant to use [Parse large XML with lxml](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16565995) instead, but I fumbled the duplicate UI. Ubuntu's answer is better still, someone reopen and re-close as dupe of [lxml etree xmlparser namespace problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4255277)